# Search all records using bash within some timeframe

Tags: bash, csv, search, awk, time

I have a csv file with data like:

```
67940,"Alpha",ISS3425345,12/9/2014 21:12,
69542,"Beta",ISS03425324,1/16/2015 11:56,
69761,"Gamma",ISS02345,1/22/2015 12:54,
```

With comma as delimiter. The 4-rd field is a timestamp of record creation. I need to write a script to input as arguments start and end of time-frame to search all records within this time-frame.

My current progress:

```
#!/bin/bash


SearchStart=$1
SearchEnd=$2

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
if [ ! -f "$DIR/Output_data.csv" ]; then 
touch $DIR/Output_data.csv 
fi

while IFS= read -r current_escalation; do
Timestamp=$( echo $current_escalation | cut -d',' -f4 )


(Here is some script to search records from SearchStart to SearchEnd)

done <$DIR/input_data.csv
```

I need script, which returns ALL results within timeframe. For example, start date is 15 September 2014, end date 20 October 2015. And I need all records from 5 September 2014 to 20 October 2015

Comment: `bash` is not the tool for this, use `awk`

Comment: Or try downloading and using [`dategrep`](https://github.com/mdom/dategrep)

Comment: note you can directly get `$Timestamp` by saying `while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 _`; this will store the first field in `$col1`, the second in `$col2` and so on.

Comment: @Inian, can yo provide some code example on awk?

Comment: @VasiliyVegas: There are lot of similar answers here, make an attempt, and post your efforts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`GNU awk`**

**One liner**

```
awk -F, -vstartd="12/9/2014 22:00:00" -vendd="1/22/2015 10:00:00" 'function df(dt, d){split(dt,d,/[/: ]/); return mktime(d[3]" "d[1]" "d[2]" "d[4]" "d[5]" "0)}{s=df($4)} s >=df(startd) && s<=df(endd)' file
```

**Explanation**

```
# Set field separator comma (-F,)
# Set startd and endd variable, in your case within bash script
# you can do -vstartd="$1" and -vendd="$2" for searching 
awk -F, -vstartd="12/9/2014 22:00:00" -vendd="1/22/2015 10:00:00" '

# function which takes input in
# month-day-year hour:minute format and
# returns Unix time

function df(dt, d)
{ 
    split(dt,d,/[/: ]/) 
    return mktime(d[3]" "d[1]" "d[2]" "d[4]" "d[5]" "0)
 }
 {
   # we do not want to call function twice for below statement
   # so assigning converted value to variable s

   s=df($4)                                 
 } 
 # So if variable s is greater than or equal to start datetime and
 # less than or equal to enddatetime
 # we get boolean true ( default operation print $0 takes place),
 # hence print current record/row 

 s >=df(startd) && s<=df(endd)   

' file                    # Input file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat f
67940,"Alpha",ISS3425345,12/9/2014 21:12,
69542,"Beta",ISS03425324,1/16/2015 11:56,
69761,"Gamma",ISS02345,1/22/2015 12:54,
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F, -vstartd="12/9/2014 22:00:00" -vendd="1/22/2015 10:00:00" 'function df(dt, d){split(dt,d,/[/: ]/); return mktime(d[3]" "d[1]" "d[2]" "d[4]" "d[5]" "0)}{s=df($4)} s >=df(startd) && s<=df(endd)' f
69542,"Beta",ISS03425324,1/16/2015 11:56,
```

Comment: it's marvelous! Thanks for help!

Comment: Another question - can you rewrite your awk string to put all output into some file or variable? Because I don't quite understand how to do this in awk.

Comment: You just have to redirect o/p like this at the end  inputfiile >outputfile

Comment: Thanks! It helped as well!